# Meteor iron-router - Can I have multiple data sources in the route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an application built with Meteor that uses Iron Router. My layout uses multiple yield templates and I'd like to pass through different data to each one.

It successfully passes through tasks to the tasksList template, but doesn't pass through selectedTask to the taskDetail template.

Is it possible to have multiple data sources and is this the right way to go about it? And if yes, then why is it not working?

Thanks in advance! :-)

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('tasksList', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    template: 'tasksList',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'taskDetail': {to: 'rightTemplate'}
    },
    data: {
        tasks: function(){ return Tasks.find() },
        selectedTask: function() { return Tasks.findOne() }
    }
});
});

<template name="layout">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="left-pane">
            {{yield}}
        </div>
        <div class="right-pane">
            {{yield 'rightTemplate'}}
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<template name="tasksList">
    <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            <li>{{detail}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="taskDetail">
    {{#each selectedTask}}
        <div>{{detail}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: It does the same thing if I have the data like this... `data: {
   tasks: [{detail: 'foo'}, {detail: 'foo'}],
   selectedTask: [{detail: 'bar'}, {detail: 'bar'}]`
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, both those methods work for me now. I must have had a wrong template name or something similar.

You can have multiple data sources as shown in the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `selectedTask` as a single object (with `findOne`), but in the `taskDetail` template, you use `{{#each selectedTask}}{{detail}}{{/each}}`.  What happens if you simply have `{{detail}}` as the body of that template?